# Keep stash after git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter

Tags: git, git-stash

I recently split out my repository (residing in `bigproj`) using `git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter deep/in/my/project`. Then, I moved `.git` directory to `deep/in/my/project`.

Now, stash is in a strange state, where the top stash is something like:

```
stash@{0}: filter-branch: rewrite
```

I can't drop this stash, as I get this error (after `git stash drop`):

```
refs/stash@{0}: not a valid stashed state
```

Now, even if I know the refid of stash@{1}, it still contains diffs for files in `bigproj` hierarchy. Is it possible to re-write stash data, so that it only contains files belonging to `deep/in/my/project` hierarchy?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem after using `git filter-branch`. The following command prunes the stash completely and therefore also deletes the entries created by `git filter-branch`. **Warning!** that all stashed changes may be impossible to recover after calling this command, so make sure to apply all other stashed states before you call the command.

```
    git stash clear
```

Comment: But I don't want to kill the whole stash, I want to keep it, just without parts that are not in the repo anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have to do the `drop` and `pop` before you move the `.git` directory.  You can always re-stash it after you move.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work. Even if I try `git stash drop` before moving the `.git` dir, I get the same error. What do you mean by re-stash?

Comment: Hmm, apparently `stash` doesn't survive the filter-branch process for some reason.  You're probably going to have to go back to your unfiltered state and just commit those changes instead, then after the filter do a `git reset HEAD~1` to make them uncommitted again.